# Merge two partitions into one running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

My hard drive was split into two partitions when new:

1. `A` = 40.5GB (useable)
2. `B`  =  189GB (usable)

It is a 64-bit machine with Windows 7 Professional. I, not being very computer savvy, went to install all my software in the default directory suggested by the software which is `C:`.

I have now found that the software, including Windows 7 Professional, has installed on BOTH partitions. For example, all the Windows files found on Partition `A` are also on Partition `B`.

Problem being that now `A` is nearly full.

I would prefer no partitions as I find it confusing. How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What software did you use to accomplish this? Are you possibly running backup software that is copying your c: drive to the other partition?

Comment: Something strange must be going on here.  It does not make sense that you would have copies on both partitions.   @Scandalist might have the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would have everything installed into both places, but to try to answer anyway:

I think you have to find a way to delete everything from the second partition, and the easiest way to do this might be to start over with a fresh install.  This might even be too complicated for you to do on your own, but at least that would give you a way to create only one partition.

Comment: I've resigned myself to probably having to do a clean reinstall. What are the DOS commands to create one partition only or is there another way of doing it?

Comment: It's been a while since I installed Windows, but I seem to recall that it lets you create partitions before the process begins.

Comment: Kevin, problem solved - I used the Easyus Partition Manager to wipre clean partition B and to increase the size of Partition A to include that of B. So now only one partition and all software still intact! A very happy outcome this time. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Great!  You might add your own answer to guide future readers.